# Intersection of modified Bessel functions with different scaling

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

Let $0< s_1 < s_2$ and $0<Z_1<Z_2$, consider functions $F_j:[0, \infty)\to [0, \infty)$ defined by $$F_j(t) = \frac{1}{Z_j} I_0(2\sqrt{ts_j}),$$ where $j = 1,2$ and $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. I want to show $F_1$ and $F_2$ intersects only once.

Attempt: Using $I_0(0)=1$, we know $F_1(0) > F_2(0)$. Using large argument asymptotic for $I_0$ and $s_1 < s_2$, it is easy to see $F_2$ is much larger than $F_1$ for large $t$, so an intersection must exist.

I tried to calculate the derivative for the difference, but unfortunately the difference is not monotone for all choices of the parameters. Are there other ways to pursue this?

Thank you

Comment: This can be proved by taking logarithm and using $I_0' = I_1$ and $I_1/I_0$ is strictly increasing.